# How to create "drag and select" chart like on Stackoverflow?

Tags: c#, jquery, .net, html, css

How to create similar drag and select chart, or which Jquery plugin to use to replicate this effect? The graph would have to read values of some sort so it can fill the chart and have a starting and ending point, now, selecting can be done in two ways: 1. Dragging mouse and selecting range of values, or, 2. Having two dragable selectors that imitate start-end point of graph? This solution can be done in Jquery, JS,HTML5, CSS3, or some .net component...

Case 1:

[image]

Case 2:

[image]

Eny ideas?

Comment: look up the API from google charts http://code.google.com/intl/sl-SI/apis/chart/ and Highcharts http://www.highcharts.com/

Comment: @Rumplin - Thanks, google charts look great, I'l take a look... Any other ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I love to use [Highcharts](http://www.highcharts.com/). Check you this demo and see if that fills your criteria:
http://www.highcharts.com/stock/demo/column

Comment: Thanks, HighCharts are great looking, but not open-source, do you know any pure jquery plugin that is OpenSource?

Comment: Anything cheaper? This one looks too pricy for just one control.

Answer (score 1):

js https://dc-js.github.io/dc.js/

Its based on d3.js and open source.  It has everything you need.  You can even build interactive charts.

If you need more chart types you can try https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/annotationchart

I have done dashboards with combination of these tow.  By which you can provide good user interaction.

Hope it helps

Comment: is it possible in chart Js

Comment: Thank you, even plotly has this now.